# How to organize a python project that has both an executable and a package with the same name

Tags: python, linux

I often create python projects that offer both a package and an executable where it makes sense to call them by the same name. For example, I created a password program utility [abraxas](http://nurdletech.com/linux-utilities/abraxas) that includes a program that generates passwords for me, and also provides a python library package that allows me to access passwords from other python scripts. Whenever I do this I struggle with organizing my files. I have the following constraints that I am trying to satisfy:

1. Once installed, both the executable and the library should have the same name to highlight the relationship between the two (meaning that I would like to run the program using 'abraxas' and import the package with 'import abraxas').
2. I must be able to run the program from the source directory without formally installing the executable (to speed up debugging).
3. I must be able to directly import the package into the executable.
4. I would like to avoid hacking sys.path.
5. I am using linux, so I don't want to add silly extensions to my executable, such as .exe.

Normally the executable and package would be in the same directory, but this does not work in this case because the names conflict.

Alternatively, I could place the executable in a different directory, but then the program would not run without first installing it because it cannot naturally find the package.

The only solution I have found to this problem is to change the name of the executable in my source directory and place it next to the package directory; then rename the executable after installing it.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't think there is any good solution because that is not really a good thing to do.  If anything, you could put the script (or code that imports and runs the script code) and the library both into the same file, with an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, which will run only if the file is directly executed.

Comment: Generally the packages are big enough so that they don't fit into one file. What is it about what I am trying to do that you think is not a good thing to do (perhaps you could just give a number)?

Comment: @AugustWest did you ever get a good solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I use entry points. In the setup.py file I add:entry_points = {                                                             
        'console_scripts': ['abraxas = abraxas.main:main'],                
    },